# Style Attribute Manipulation wiht native Javascript on FF

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, styles, native

I tried to find a related question but could not find anything that sounded alike.

Im building a small javascript Slider plugin for multiple projects at our company.
Therefore i need to do basic style manipulation on some Elements in the DOM.
I tested this on current Chrome +ChromeOnAndroid, Safari +SafariIOS, Opera +OperaMobile.
When i try to do this on Firefox it seems like the Style attributes dont get touched at all:
Heres the code ( or the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pna9ueLn/)) :

```
// the html
<div id="testwrapper">
</div>

// the javascript
(function(){

    var extend = function(source, additions) {
        for (var addition in additions) {
            source[addition] = additions[addition];
        }
    };

    var testEl = document.getElementById('testwrapper');

    var testStyles = {
        width: '150px',
        height: '150px',
        padding: '5px',
        margin: '5px'
    };
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        extend(testEl.style, testStyles);
    }, 15000)

}());
```

It's pretty obvious what im trying to accomplish.
Im taking the style attributes the element has and try to extend them by the ones i give in *testStyles*.
This seemed very straight forward to me and much easier then writing down all attributes i want to change this way :

```
testEl.style.width = 'Xpx';
testEl.style.height = 'Ypx';
// and so on
```

This way it would work in ff but..
that would blow up my code because i will have different conditions were some attributes may change and some may not.

So here comes the Question: 

Is there a way to get the same result as in Chrome etc. in Firefox or am I doing something wrong. 
Is this way of manipulating the style attribute supported in FF at all?

Thanks for your help.

PS: I dont need anyone telling me to use jQuery instead. Keep that in mind please.

Comment: works for me in chrome, what's the problem again? do remember that css names and style property names sometimes differ aside from just camelCaseConversion, for example cssFloat

Comment: it's likely easier to store your css as strings and setAttribute("style", origcss+";"+newcss) to reoncile them; that avoid all the literal escaping and camelCaseConversion

Comment: the problem is that this doesn't work in Firefox.. i mean my code not your advices... I read that the way doing this over setAttribute is not best practice either and it doesn't really fit to what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: you were assigning style, which ff doesn't like. working: http://jsfiddle.net/pna9ueLn/3/

Comment: hm , i tested this out before. Niet the Dark Absol pointed out the same thing and it looked like that didn't help either but it seems like it does :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because objects are passed around by reference, you don't need `return source;` and you don't need `testEl.style =` either. Try removing these two things and see if that fixes the problem in Firefox - it probably doesn't like you doing a complete re-assign of the `style` object ;)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I should have said that i just wrote this test case to show my problem. The things you pointed out are helpful but dont solve the problem :/. I changed the two points in the code